# Compare javascript objects deeply and keep key from object 1 and values from object 2

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare javascript objects deeply, keep keys from the base object and copy different values from the new object inside the base object.

I think it's kinda mapping between keys I would like to keep and key from the new object.

base object :

```
{

    name: "Will",
    lastname: "Smith",
    age: "45",
    movies : [
        {
            title: "Hancock",
            price: {
                amount: "1500"
            }
        },
        {
            title: "Gemooni",
            price: {
                amount: "2500"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

new value to copy in base object :

```
{

    actor_name: "Will",
    actor_firstname: "Smith",
    actor_age: "45",
    cinema : [ // for movies
        {
            title: "Hancock",
            price: {
                amount: "1900"
            }
        },
        {
            title: "Gemini",
            price: {
                amount: "3000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, I want to keep value for actor_name and copy it to an actor in the first object. Same for all values include nested objects.

Result :

```html
{

    name: "Will",
    lastname: "Smith",
    age: "45",
    movies : [
        {
            title: "Hancock",
            price: {
                amount: "1900"
            }
        },
        {
            title: "Gemini",
            price: {
                amount: "3000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: `base_object['movies'] = new_object['cinema']`.

Comment: will the keys be always the same between base object and new object ?

Comment: How do you know that the `name` key in the first object corresponds to the `actor_name` key in the second object (same question for other keys)? Based on the values?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai yep, they won't change

Comment: @slider I know before to compare the keys and they wont change. Here, actor_name = name, actor_age = age ...
So I think, I need a kind of mapping while I compare objects to match keys and copy the value inside my base object

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create mapping object.

```
var src = {
  a1: "foo_a",
  b1: "foo_b",
}

var map = {
  a: "a1",
  b: "b1",
}
```

Now the solution would be

```
function mapper(src,map) {
  var result = {};
  for(let i in map) result[i] = src[map[i]];
  return result;
}

var dst = mapper(src,map); // { a: "foo_a", b: "foo_b" }
```

This doesn't solve deep mapping directly, but you could use special prefixes in `map` object to tell the mapper function that the value is object.